# Digital asset management

Tags: database-design, database-recommendation

I'm working in a company that currently develops Media Asset Management system and now we want to improve our system for document files. I have to search nearly thousand `.doc` and `.pdf` files and index them.

I want to use SQL Server's filestream and full-text search capabilities for this job but my colleagues warn me about accessibility and database size. When you use SQL Server, it saves document files in its share and change the file name so database file size is getting bigger and bigger.

They offered me to use Windows Search Service. In this way, indexing and storing is not my job so my database will be clean and accessing files are relatively easy.

I'm confused. Which way do I prefer or is there any other way?